# Проблема утечки данных при использовании метода sleep()

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть простейшая реализация `Lock` механизма через sleep():

```
class Lock01 {
    private boolean isLocked = false;

    void lock() throws InterruptedException {
        while (isLocked) {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }

        isLocked = true;
    }

    void unlock() {
        isLocked = false;
    }
}
```

Вызываю:

```
public class Intro {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Intro().doCounter();
    }

    private final Lock01 lock = new Lock01();
    private int count = 0;

    private void increment() {
        try {
            lock.lock();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        count++;

        lock.unlock();
    }

    private void doCounter() {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
                    increment();
                }
                System.out.println("count = " + count + " thread 1");
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
                    increment();
                }
                System.out.println("count = " + count + " thread 2");
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
count = 1000681 thread 1
count = 1999988 thread 2
```

Где происходит утечка и почему такая маленькая? Что за сценарий должен произойти чтобы у нас вместо `2000000` получилось `1999988`?

Comment: Похоже что иногда происходит `race condition` на переменной `isLock` и в это время два потока одновременно изменяют `count`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема здесь:

```
while (isLocked) { 
    Thread.sleep(1);
}
isLocked = true;
```

Считывание и установка значения здесь две отдельные операции, соответственно, оба потока могут считать значение false и установить true.

Для проверки можно объединить считывание и установку в атомарную операцию. Например, с помощью [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html):

```
private AtomicBoolean isLocked = new AtomicBoolean();

void lock() throws InterruptedException {
    while (!isLocked.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    }
}
```